# Module not found: Can't resolve - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a problem with the relative path for my react app. It seems super simple but I've double checked everything and I still can't get it to work.

The path is src > components(folder) > Navigation(folder) > navigation.js

The terminal says: "Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/Navigation/navigation' in '/Users/misbahhemraj/Desktop/facefind/src'"

This is my code in my app.Js:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import navigation from './components/Navigation/navigation';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
    <div className="App">
        <navigation />
        {/*<Logo />
        <ImageLinkForm />
        <FaceRecognition />*/}
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

This is my code in navigation.js

```
    import React from 'react';

const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <nav>
            <p> Sign Out </p>
        </nav>
    )
}


export default navigation;
```

I've tried changing the ports and changing the syntax of the import statement but I can't get it it work. Any advice would be appreciated - thank you so much!

Comment: well, you have made a typo in the `navigation.js` file, you are exporting `navigation` while the component name is `Navigation `, so fixing this typo will remove your error

Answer (score 0):

Look at your export component name, you have navigation and your component name it´s Navigation

```
import React from 'react';

const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <nav>
            <p> Sign Out </p>
        </nav>
    )
}


export default Navigation;
```